# How to plot estimates from different models in one plot

Tags: r, plot, mixed-models

I'm performing a linear Mixed Effect for two different drugs. I used the contrast statement to determine the impact of time.

I'm trying to plot estimates from different models in one plot.
This is the output of the model 1

```
confint(model1) 
  Estimate       lwr      upr
1 == 0 2.969735 -1.846697 5.786166
2 == 0 4.163577  0.646791 5.680363
3 == 0 2.193842 -3.377740 5.765425
```

the output from model 2

```
Linear Hypotheses:
       Estimate lwr     upr    
1 == 0 65.0877  60.5934 65.5820
2 == 0 65.8362  62.9191 65.7532
3 == 0  0.9484  -4.6095  6.1064
```

I'm trying to plot the
estimates  and CI of model 1(3 == 0 2.193842 -3.377740 5.765425) and model 2(3 == 0  0.9484  -4.6095  6.1064) in one plot 
How can you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@thus__'s answer is fine.  You can do this even more easily with the `dotwhisker` package (although it's good to know the manual `tidy`+combine for cases where you want more control).

Set up models:

```
library(lme4)
m1 <- lmer(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject),sleepstudy)
m2 <- update(m1, . ~ . + I(Days^2))
```

Plot:

```
library(broom.mixed)
library(dotwhisker)
dwplot(list(m1,m2),effects="fixed")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what type of model object you are creating.

I would recommend using the broom package to create a data frame of estimates and bind these together.

```
library(tidyverse)

lm1 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = mtcars)

lm2 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species, data = iris)

bind_rows(
  broom::tidy(lm1),
  broom::tidy(lm2)
) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = term, y = estimate)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip()
```